# Cannot import certificate into keychain

Tags: xcode, keychain

I am trying to deploy an iOS app to a device. There are two members in my team with developer enrollments.

My team member created a certificate from another mac and exported it. I then imported the certificate into my keychain app. The keychain app is showing the certificate but in Xcode organizer when I refresh from **my own developer account** xcode says  **Valid signing identity not found**

Xcode version : 4.6.3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check these steps:

1. export p.12 file from certificate in first mac.
2. set password to file. (iv'e sometimes seen issues raised when password is not set)
3. open p.12 file in second mac.
4. type in password.
5. download and open appropriate provision file.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try  import from another mac and export team in organizer? I had such problems before but i can't remember truely. Your team is valid with green mark in Teams section in organizer?